# Hibernate doesn't update or delete, but does insert

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on an existing database and have created Hibernate entities. The problematic entity is `OrderHeader`, which has a list of `OrderLine`. Here is my mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orderline")
public class OrderLine implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "OrderLineID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer orderLineID;

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
OrderHeader orderHeader;
}

...

@Entity
@Table(name = "orderheader")
public class OrderHeader implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "OrderHeaderID")
int orderHeaderId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
List<OrderLine> orderLineList;
}
```

All operations performed are on detached entities. When i use `session.save` to insert a new `OrderHeader` with a list of `OrderLine` everything executes perfectly. However, upon calling `session.update` on a detached, altered `OrderHeader` the only SQL statement being executed is the select statement retrieving the result of the update (which didn't happen in the first place). It gets even worse when I try to delete `OrderHeader` - despite having set `CascadeType.ALL` and `orphanRemoval = true` on the join upon calling `session.delete` hibernate is updating `OrderLine`s in the list by setting the `OrderHeaderID` as null, which throws an exception.

The DDL for both tables contain just plain data definitions with a single simple primary key. Every single DAO operation is performed in an invidual session.

Could it be that I'm missing something? The relationship annotations seem ok, I'm pretty sure I'm using the right methods to access the database (although I've tried every one out there). I've literally ran out of options. Any advice is welcome, thanks

EDIT: Updated the definitions, now I get `ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'dbname.orderheader_orderline' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Your problem is clearly the @OneToMany mapping which should look like this :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="orderHeader")
List<OrderLine> orderLineList;
```

- the mappedBy value to tell JPA that it is a bidirectionnal relation
- no @JoinColumn : it has already been set in the @ManyToOne

2 - that said, keep the cascading and stuff only on the @OneToMany and remove :

```
(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

from the @ManyToOne ..

**EDIT** here is what your code should look like :
@ManyToOne with the @JoinColumn ... and @OneToMany with the property mappedBy

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orderline")
public class OrderLine implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "OrderLineID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer orderLineID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "OrderHeaderID")
OrderHeader orderHeader;
}

...

@Entity
@Table(name = "orderheader")
public class OrderHeader implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "OrderHeaderID")
int orderHeaderId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="orderHeader")
List<OrderLine> orderLineList;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have left only the `@ManyToOne` annotation on `OrderLine` side and left `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)` on the `OrderHeader` side - but now i get JDBCException upon delete - Table 'dbname.orderheader_orderline' doesn't exist

Comment: did you add that mappedBy value ? ... can you post your corrected code again please ?

Comment: posted updated version, should the mappedBy reference the class or table name?

Comment: not correct ... i'll just edit my answer, and give you the right solution

Comment: for your last question : mappedBy should reference the property name

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I'm afraid that's not good aswell: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: model.entity.OrderHeader.orderLineList`

Comment: Sorry, i left the @JoinColumn on the OneToMany side ... lol ... i have edited my answer again

Comment: Thanks alot, the delete is working properly now! Still don't know why update isn't working, but now i suppose the error is elsewhere

Comment: glad that it helped ... don't forget that's a bidirectional relationship, so when adding or removing a OrderLine, you should do it in both sides, i.e. : `orderHeader.getOrderLineList().add(orderLine); orderLine.setOrderHeader(orderHeader);`